# Do the intersectional feminist organizations concern themselves with the fate of the kidnapped in Gaza?

Tags: terrorism, hamas, 2023-israel-hamas-war, feminism

As in, **had any of them demanded the release of the [hostages](https://www.jns.org/israeli-hostage-believed-to-have-given-birth-in-captivity/) or allowing the Red Cross access to them? Information about them?** Since October 7, we know nothing about the fate of the kidnapped.

According to the Thai community, on social media, among the kidnapped Thai workers there was a pregnant woman who likely gave birth since then.

There are a lot of demonstrations on campuses, but they only seem to cover one side of the conflict, and the hostages seem to slip under the radar. Why is that?

Any condemnation of how Hamas treated women from those feminist organizations?

Comment: Can you spell a bit more precisely which are the "intersectional feminist" organizations you have in mind? I looked briefly at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersectionality but I don't see any organizations listed.

Comment: @Fizz any transnational, intersectual feminist, or i make this easier for you. ANY feminist organisation which is a netural side to the conflict (not israeli or palestinian) They're usually so vocal in their opposition to violence towards women.

Comment: Voting to close - I really don't understand what feminism or feminist organisations have to do with condemning terrorism or kidnapping? You may as well ask - did the Boys Scout condemn Hamas? Or has some poet's society condemned Hamas? Please re-write your question and make your intentions clear.

Comment: FWTW, the irony is that Al-Jazeera complains conversely that Palestinian women are being ignored by Western feminists https://www.aljazeera.com/opinions/2023/10/23/western-feminism-and-its-blind-spots-in-the-middle-east I guess you can never have enough condemnations, depending on your viewpoint.

Comment: @sfxedit un women and other feminist organisations are an important part of the public discourse. but it's not a good question for SE, i understand it now. "intersectional feminism" gets you downwotes and shock here :) this part of an otherwise sad subject is pretty amusing

Comment: @ForShaniNicoleLouk I agree with you that the hostages are not getting enough attention. My issue with your question is that it lacks details. Questions here need to show some research effort from you too, to make the job of answering it easier for others. For example, you ask about about intersectional feminist organisations but don't provide any background on them, nor why you think they should be concerned about this political situation. At the same time you talk about campus activities and ask why they aren't concerned about the hostages, which seems unrelated to your original question.

Comment: @ForShaniNicoleLouk Just edit the question to convey your intent properly, and improve it by providing clarifications to the concerns raised by others in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Several feminist organizations have spoken out, although often much later than in the immediate aftermath of the Hamas terrorist acts of October 7, 2023. This alone makes one question their motives (had they spoken out against the Hamas terrorist acts against women, why hadn't they spoken out earlier?).

Several feminist organizations also spoke in general terms referring to violence on both sides. Several spoke out only **against Israel**, not mentioning Hamas treatment of women at all. See a few examples below, taken from press releases of the large feminist organizations.

Anecdotally, I have not seen in the mainstream media any photos of feminist rallies in support of female hostages taken by Hamas. Any photos of posters in support of hostages at rallies have been attributed to general pro-Israel and/or anti-Hamas rallies.

**References:**

> NOW Condemns Violent Hateful Attacks Against Israel
> Released on October 7, 2023
>
> National NOW President Christian F. Nunes issued the following
> statement upon the attacks reported in Israel
>
> “A terrorist army has invaded the land of Israel, murdering innocent
> civilians and taking whole communities hostage. ‘We are at war,’ Prime
> Minister Netanyahu told his nation, and today, the whole world is
> holding its breath.
>
> While the day unfolds, NOW members are sticking fast to our core
> principles of human rights and freedom from fear, violence, and
> division. The rise in antisemitism and violent attacks on Jewish
> communities here and around the world underscore our alarm.
>
> The people of Israel live in constant fear of days like today. This is
> what happens when hate has no boundaries.
>
> NOW supports the right of the Jewish people to live without fear or
> violence, and we condemn antisemitism in all its forms.”

*[NOW Condemns Violent Hateful Attacks Against Israel - National Organization for Women](https://now.org/media-center/press-release/now-condemns-violent-hateful-attacks-against-israel/), October 7, 2023.*

---

> Sarah Hendriks, UN Women Deputy Executive Director, ad interim, said: “UN Women has called for an immediate humanitarian ceasefire and unimpeded access for humanitarian aid, including food, water, fuel, and health supplies that are critical for the survival of women and girls in the Gaza Strip. It is imperative that we ensure immediate access to services for women and girls and ensure the prevention of gender-based violence. As the international community seeks to respond to this crisis, we must also wholeheartedly support and invest in women-led organizations, which are at the front-line of the humanitarian response, and promote the meaningful participation of women in humanitarian and political processes.”

*[Press release: UN Women report reveals devastating impact of the crisis in Gaza on women and girls | UN Women – Headquarters](https://www.unwomen.org/en/news-stories/press-release/2023/10/press-release-un-women-report-reveals-devastating-impact-of-the-crisis-in-gaza-on-women-and-girls), 20 OCTOBER 2023*

---

> We condemn Hamas’s attacks on civilians on October 7 and call for a return of the hostages, and we condemn state leaders in Israel who have led a violent escalation and total blockade of critical humanitarian aid in Gaza, leading to thousands of additional civilian deaths. There must be an immediate ceasefire and an end to the genocide, collective punishment, and forcible transfer of the Palestinian people in Gaza.

*[Feminist Leaders Call to #StopTheMassacre in Palestine - Global Fund for Women](https://www.globalfundforwomen.org/latest/article/palestine-stop-the-massacre/), NOVEMBER 3, 2023*

---

[image: “Gaza: Genocide and Resistance”]

*[Palestinian Feminist Collective | Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/palestinianfeministcollective/posts/pfbid02xwnzPVGGNSL28PREDsEvB2YnAbGTQNCiUF5v96UFPzAQU3UQcYc176LgCVpLjgHl), November 14, 2023.*

---

[image: CODEPINK is a feminist grassroots organization working to support peace & human rights & end U.S. wars & militarism]

> CODEPINK is a feminist grassroots organization working to support peace & human rights & end U.S. wars & militarism.

*[CODEPINK (@codepink) / X](https://twitter.com/codepink)*

> This week CODEPINK was joined by Palestinian women, including mothers, grandmothers and daughters, as well as the Doctors Against Genocide. We made our way through the Senate corridors urging all women of the US Senate to call for a ceasefire in Gaza.

*[CODEPINK: Check out our activities for the Week of November 13, 2023](https://www.codepink.org/november_13_2023)*

Comment: AFAICT, the NOW statement you link to was issued on Oct 7. So how is that "much later than in the immediate aftermath of the Hamas terrorist acts"? Are you complaining that "taking whole communities hostage" was not explicit enough?

Comment: @Fizz Several others were not, though. As I mentioned, *"although often much later than in the immediate aftermath of the Hamas terrorist acts of October 7, 2023."*

Comment: I guess you're referring to UN Women? Their board is dominated by countries from Asia and Africa, both of which refused to condemn Hamas at the UN (by and large).

Comment: @Fizz Yes, plus Global Fund for Women too. I plan to expand on my answer later. It is an interesting question. Thank you for your answer and comments!

Comment: Interesting point about Code Pink. I admit I had never heard of them. But checking out their wiki page, they seem far more concerned with US "imperialism" and anti-war activism than other matters. So I'd say they are first and foremost that and feminism seems to be a secondary focus, despite their name. * (McCain called them "lowlife scum!")

Answer (score 3):

FWTW, [Women for Women International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_for_Women_International), which is US-based, but was founded by an Arab couple, [said](https://www.womenforwomen.org/node/2314):

> October 11, 2023
>
> We are horrified by the atrocities on women and their families in the Israel-Hamas war. We are mourning all the lives lost. We grieve the brutal massacre of civilians in Israel and **we fear for the safety of the hostages**. Also, we grieve the impact of the bombings on civilians, including women and children trapped in Gaza.

Arguably this organization is more focused on women in war zones than your typical feminist organization though.

---

FWTW, the Wikipedia page on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersectionality only mentions two organization as being [at least partly] dedicated to that

- the Women's Institute for Science, Equity, and Race (WISER), based in the US. Searching their site doesn't return anything at all for Israel, Palestine or Gaza, although there is one story tangentially about the Taliban (in a list of documentaries). So my guess is that WISER doesn't discuss foreign [to the US] issues much.
- the African American Policy Forum. Their site is pretty hard to search; I had to use google with "site:", but again they seem to have zero stories about Israel, Palestine, Gaza, or even the Taliban. They do have stories like "Black Girls Matter" etc. (found while searching for "black" in the same fashion.)

Comment: but apart from the condemnation of the original attack, anything to put pressure on Hamas, demand, involve the red cross, and ask further information? it's an ongoing event with the hostages held there. should be something, a followup, but i couldnt find anything. and i've searched. all that comes up is just israeli media and organisations.

Comment: @ForShaniNicoleLouk: Do Western feminist organizations pressure the Taliban? Where's the leverage? They did complain more when the Western-back Afghanistan government did little. https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/medialse/2021/09/02/afghanistan-and-the-colonial-project-of-feminism-dismantling-the-binary-lens/

Comment: but the israel-palestinian confict is star news. even Syria condemns how inhumane it is :) and those feminist organizations are very focused on this particular conflict. so if they are, why completely ignore the kidnapped? is there a difference between the thay victim and the palestinian one? innocent women suffer on both sides, no?

Comment: @ForShaniNicoleLouk: "those organizations are very focused on this particular conflict" [citation needed] OTOH there was a war to “liberate Afghan women.” https://www.thenation.com/article/world/white-feminists-wanted-to-invade/

Comment: really. you need me to prove to you that there are demonstrations all over the world about this particular conflict.

Comment: And yes, funnily enough HRW blasted western gov'ts even for that [post-2022]:

https://www.hrw.org/news/2022/03/23/what-do-canada-france-germany-and-sweden-owe-afghan-women

"If feminist foreign policy does not mean standing up for Afghan women and girls in this crisis, it begs the question of what feminist foreign policy means — and risks the conclusion: not much."

Comment: i thought there's a lot of involvement. https://centreforfeministforeignpolicy.org/afghanistan-projects/ 
https://disabilityglobalsouth.files.wordpress.com/2021/01/dgs08_01_01.pdf https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=112534  https://asksource.info/resources/life-becomes-harder-intersectional-feminist-lens-disabled-experience-women-afghanistan https://press.un.org/en/2023/gashc4376.doc.htm theres a lot of involvement. i am searching for similar results for the kidnapped women. or for palestinian women under hamas' rule. against child brides, teenager girl suicide bombers